# filter_input for session variables

Tags: php, session

Is there some equivalent of `filter_input` I can use with `$_SESSION`as I would with `$_POST`?

When I tried it gives the error :

`Warning: filter_input(): INPUT_SESSION is not yet implemented`

```
session_start();
$x=filter_input(INPUT_SESSION, 'x');
if ($x){
    echo $x;
}
```

php version: `PHP Version 5.5.12-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1`

Comment: Why would you need to filter it? It is not user-provided.

Comment: @jeroen hmm, fair point. the main reason is I have use `filter_input` as a convention now as it saves checking for `isset($_POST['x'])`

Comment: You could use something like `$x = isset($_SESSION['x']) ? $_SESSION['x'] : NULL`. Not that much longer...

Comment: @jeroen yeah thats quite a nice solution :)

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem like you. Maybe we are so rigorous but I solved the problem without compromising any security/filter.

I used `filter_var` instead of `filter_input`.

an example is like this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['baba'] = "co";
$ses = filter_var($_SESSION['baba']);
if (!empty($ses)) {
    echo $ses;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like $_SESSION doesnt work the same that $_SERVER.
After many combinations i had a similar issue. I'll leave some of my code after fixing so you can see the difference:

Here is the original code with warnings due to direct access to these variables

```
if  (   (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin'] == false) ||
        ($_SESSION['REMOTE_ADDR'] != $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ||
        (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin'] == false) || 
        ($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] != $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) 
    ) {
    header("Location: ../login.php");
}
```

Below is the code after including filters and cleared warnings

```
if  (   (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || (filter_var($_SESSION['loggedin']) == false)) ||
        (filter_var($_SESSION['REMOTE_ADDR']) != filter_input(INPUT_SERVER,'REMOTE_ADDR')) ||
        (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || (filter_var($_SESSION['loggedin']) == false)) || 
        (filter_var($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) != filter_input(INPUT_SERVER,'HTTP_USER_AGENT') ) 
    ) {
    header("Location: ../login.php");
}
```